# python numpy.nanmean() returns Nan

Tags: python, numpy

Now, I'm coding a program with numpy array.

```
def alert(numpy_path, x1,x2,y1,y2)
    dispp = np.load(numpy_path)
    depth = 1 / dispp
    depth_f = depth.astype('float64')
    mean = np.nanmean(depth_f[x1:x2][y1:y2])
```

I want a depth numpy array's mean value. But sometimes, it returns a Nan value.
Why `np.nanmean` returns Nan values?? I don't understand.

As I known, `np.nanmean` ignores `nanvalues`. So, I expected, it returns a `float` value.

(I already read `numpy.nanmean` manual. In the manual, it said 'Compute the arithmetic mean along the specified axis, *ignoring NaNs*'.)

So, why it returns a `Nan` value. And how to fix it??

Comment: Maybe you've got nothing *but* NaNs. We can't tell. (Also, `depth_f[x1:x2][y1:y2]` doesn't mean what you think it means. You want `depth_f[x1:x2, y1:y2]`.)

Comment: @user2357112 OMG.. You are right! When I get a `Nan value`, I printed `depth_f`. There is just empty space. And also, I fixed `depth_f[x1:x2, y1:y2]`. Thank you very much!